# Do Web Animations work in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Dartium raises a "Not Supported" exception when calling `Element.animate()`, and Chrome, via dart2js, doesn't do anything at all.

Web Animations via JavaScript work completely fine in the aforementioned browsers.

Does Dart actually support Web Animations?

Comment: What Dart/Dartium version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `Exception: Unsupported operation: [info: ../../third_party/WebKit/Source/bindings/core/dart/custom/DartElementCustom.cpp:100]` even with an example that worked months ago.

Please create a bug report.

Comment: I took your comment to mean that Web Animations worked at some point via Dart, so they're supported, but currently not working due to some kind of bug in Dart.

Comment: I played around with it about a year ago and several things worked already back then.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in the Element.animate API. It looks like the problem is that it takes Map arguments, and it's not being correctly converted, so in dart2js we're passing a Dart LinkedHashMap to JS, and it doesn't understand it. So it's just a matter of convincing the generation script to add the right type conversions. At least for dart2js, I haven't yet investigated Dartium.

Comment: Fixed now in dart2js. Will be in 1.10.